# undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.SHORT')

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with the dependency "react-native-simple-toast", I get the following error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.SHORT')
```

the problem is at the moment of using

```
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';
```

in the code is still not using "Toast", and even then the error appears, I do not know if it could be a problem of compatibility with the dependencies, the current version that I use "react-native-simple-toast" is "^ 0.0.8 ", if someone knows something, I would be very grateful if you would help me.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `react-native link react-native-simple-toast`? also, have you tried reinstalling all the dependencies? if yes, try reinstalling npm then reinstalling all dependencies again.

Comment: I had done it before, I did it again but in the order that you mentioned but I still get the same error

Comment: are you using ios or android? if its ios, try unlinking, linking and running it with ```react-native run-ios```. also try using rnpm link, then rebuild the app. if its android, checkout [react-native-toast-android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toastandroid)

Comment: I'm trying it on iOS, on Android there is no problem, I make the indications you mention but when running the react-native run-ios the console tells me that there is no folder runIOS / runIOS.js, I'm trying to create the folder but the answers and solutions that I find do not generate folders

Comment: Well, why not just use [react-native-rn-toast-](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rn-toast) .. what's the difference? Also, you have set up your Root component correctly right?

Comment: the problem was in specific with Simple-Toast that only works with android, I started using Easy-Toast which works very well for both, in the future I will keep in mind the one you mention me, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help, `react-native-simple-toast` and `react-native-rn-toast` both didn't work for me on iOS, but Easy Toast finally did.